# Getting 403 Forbidden on AWS OpenSearch Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to setup OpenSearch Serverless but I keep running into permissions issues.

I followed everything in this tutorial:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started.html

But after I create the collection, I am unable to access the OpenSearch Dashboard either by the root user or the user that I attached to this Collection. I always get a 403 Forbidden error.

I added the policy in the documentation to my user. I made the collection public. I granted access to the Dashboard in Network Policies. I still get the 403 Forbidden error.

Any help with what could be causing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your user attached to the collection have an IAM policy allowing `aoss:DashboardsAccessAll`?

Comment: Try attaching this inline policy to your user, replacing `xxx` with your account ID: `{"Sid": "AllowDashboardAccess", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": "aoss:DashboardsAccessAll", "Resource": "arn:aws:aoss:region:xxx:dashboards/default"}`.

Comment: Try the same request using `awscurl`, we found when making the request using PHP and AWS SDK PUT/POSTS requests to AOSS would fail, while the same request in awscurl would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue - I created the AWS OpenSearch serverless collection while logged in as the root account holder. I created another "admin" IAM user, then attached that particular "admin" IAM user to the AWS OpenSearch data access policy.

I had to enable console access to my "admin" IAM user, log into the console, then was able to access the OpenSearch dashboard.